# How to static override/create operator * in a static class

Tags: c#, operators, operator-overloading, overriding

Hi i want to write some extensions for Array operation like:

**MatrixProduct**

```
public static double[][] operator *(double[][] matrixA, double[][] matrixB)
```

**MatrixVectorProduct**

```
public static double[] operator *(double[][] matrix, double[] vector)
```

and some more

Why do i want this? because as you may know there is at the moment non such operation implemented in c# and it feels more natural if i can say `matrixC = matrixA * matrixB;` insteed of `matrixC = MatrixProduct(matrixA,matrixB);` so is there a way to do this?

because if i do it like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{
    public static double[] operator *(double[][] matrix, double[] vector)
    {
        // result of multiplying an n x m matrix by a m x 1 column vector (yielding an n x 1 column vector)
        int mRows = matrix.Length; int mCols = matrix[0].Length;
        int vRows = vector.Length;

        if (mCols != vRows)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Non-conformable matrix and vector in MatrixVectorProduct");

        double[] result = new double[mRows]; // an n x m matrix times a m x 1 column vector is a n x 1 column vector

        Parallel.For(0, mRows, i =>
        {
            var row = matrix[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < mCols; ++j)
                result[i] += row[j] * vector[j];
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

An Exception tells me i can't combine a static Class and a userdefined operator so is there a work around ?

Comment: You can always define your own `Matrix` class and specify operators for that type. Actually, I don't think there's any other way here.

Comment: but i don't want to reinvent the wheel :(

Comment: Also, this would not be an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), because the first parameter is not preceded by `this`.

Comment: @WiiMaxx There's not much re-inventing going on here, your `Matrix` class could just wrap a jagged array and expose operators/methods needed (like e.g. `Transpose`). Arguably, it would be cleaner (semantically), since jagged array doesn't necessarily mean a 'matrix'.

Comment: @Corak you are right :) haven't see it, so it get's worse because it also looks like i can't use this there :D

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek it looks like i will end up with your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only overload `operator *` if one of its operands is a user-defined type, so unfortunately the answer is no.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx):

> To overload an operator on a custom class requires creating a method
>   on the class with the correct signature. The method must be named
>   "operator X" where X is the name or symbol of the operator being
>   overloaded. Unary operators have one parameter, and binary operators
>   have two parameters. **In each case, one parameter must be the same type
>   as the class or struct that declares the operator** [...]

So you are forced to either involve a custom `Matrix` class in the expression, or use a proper method that takes `double[]` arguments.

Comment: What a pity. So i have to reinvent the wheel? i don't like that :(

Comment: @WiiMaxx: There's not much to reinvent really, you can write a `Matrix` constructor that directly accepts a `double[,]` and wraps it. Incidentally, that's what your argument type should be -- a rectangular array, not `double[][]` which is a jagged array.

Comment: i need lightspeed performance so it has to be a jagged array ;)

Comment: @WiiMaxx: I really have no hands-on experience about how perf is affected, but in theory rectangular should be faster (one less indirection) unless your arrays are sparse, which does not look to be the case here. Why do you say that jagged is faster?

Comment: because a `[n,m]` is a single memory space where a `[n][m]` is jagged in `n` memory spaces so the access is faster you can test it on your one or search for **jagged array vs 2d array** it can boost the the performance incredibly based on the matrix size and algorithm up to over 100%

Comment: for example i was able to improve the performance of a Bitmap operation i found by nearly 30% and this a lot :)

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Just searched around a bit, it seems you are correct but unfortunately that is so because of CLR jitter fail. Or in other words, noone bothered to optimize that scenario properly. Sigh.

Comment: i actually more surprised that MS doesn't provide a Matrix class and noone bothered because there are many situations where you need a Matrix operation e.g. in 3d and image operation an you get is a 3x3 support from MS :D

Comment: You might be interested in Eric Lipperts [usual response to “why is feature X not implemented?”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: @Corak: Well aware of that response. Does not change the fail: pick the faster approach in theory, end up with worse performance in practice. Of course C# is not targeted at the signal processing audience, so the decision is understandable. But still unfortunate.

Comment: @Jon - Yes, I agree with the `[][] vs. [,]`. Sorry, the link was more for the "why is there no built in Matrix class".